# MaxMind API how to parse array?

Tags: php, api

My MaxMind API Call receives this array:

```
object(MaxMind\MinFraud\Model\Score)#5 (8) {
  ["disposition":protected]=>
  object(MaxMind\MinFraud\Model\Disposition)#33 (3) {
    ["action":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["reason":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["rawResponse"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["fundsRemaining":protected]=>
  float(4.94)
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(36) "604DE3C0-13DE-11E7-B630-507824A72470"
  ["ipAddress":protected]=>
  object(MaxMind\MinFraud\Model\ScoreIpAddress)#36 (2) {
    ["risk":protected]=>
    float(0.01)
    ["rawResponse"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["risk"]=>
      float(0.01)
    }
  }
```

How I get this value ["risk"]=>float(0.01) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a protected property, so your object needs to provide a method to access the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://maxmind.github.io/minfraud-api-php/), you can access the IP risk score with `$resp->ipAddress->risk` or the overall risk score with `$resp->riskScore`.

Comment: Thank you so much!